# Even after setting 301 redirect on firebase hosting, Google Search Console displays 301 redirect error

Tags: google, google-search-console, google-search, search-engine-indexing

I am using firebase hosting. At first, i used default domains but now i have changed it to custom domain. Now i changing address in google search console for the default domain but i am getting the 301 redirect error. Following is my *firebase.json* file and the google search console error screenshot.

```
    {
  "hosting": {
    "public": "root",
    "site": "ai-dream",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ],
    "redirects": [ {
    "source": "ai-dream.web.app",
    "destination": "dream-interpreter.online",
    "type": 301
  },{
    "source": "ai-dream.firebaseapp.com",
    "destination": "dream-interpreter.online",
    "type": 301
  } ]
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your redirect isn't set up correctly.  I get the same results as Google: `$ curl --head https://ai-dream.web.app/` -> `HTTP/2 200`

Comment: It looks like your configuration isn't creating a 301 redirect.  it is creating a JavaScript redirect.  I see this in the source code of the page:  `location.replace("https://dream-interpreter.online");`  I have no idea how to fix that though, because I've never used firebase.

Comment: i did this when i couldnt get the redirects done by json. Now its working but it would be good if i could do this by simple json.

Comment: This person says they got it to work https://stackoverflow.com/a/76293250/1145388 and the  they use `https://` in their `source`  then have a second entry with `:path` at the end.

Comment: i tried it with https too but it didnt redirected. May be i didnt give it enough time. let me try it one more time and wait one or two days. lets see what happens.